# What is the best way to get database password to integration tests using Maven?

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, integration-testing, maven-3

We are using Maven and Spring and current execute our tests by using System properties and test with this line.

```
mvn -Ddbuser=username -Ddbpassword=password test
```

In the past I had utilized environment variables but I read that support was going away in maven so figured it may be a bad practice.

Comment: The best practice is for your unit tests not to hit actual databases. Mock or fake all activity at the database seam. Unit tests need to run *fast*. Integration tests may hit databases, but not unit tests.

Comment: @Asaph: Your comment is absolutely true for unit tests. However the question is valid for integration tests. I'll edit the title and tags accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You could store the password as property in the settings.xml file.  Now, if storing it in a clear text bugs you as much as me, there is the --encrypt-password option for the maven that you can then store the password in the settings.xml encrypted in a profile, server, or some other section for use in your integration tests. Here's the link to the documentation on how to configure this:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html

Comment: I like Mavens encrypted password support. But How would I access the decrypted password in the test?